# How to embed image in HTML email template?

Tags: html, css, email-templates, xhtml-transitional

I have created an **Email template** using `HTML` and inline style from scratch. Now I need to add some images, at this point it's not possible to use url because it is not hosted. I tried using base64 encoding, it worked in Apple mail client, but the images are not rendering in Gmail. Is there any way to embed image in html supported by all email clients?

Comment: how did you embed the base64 image in your html?

Comment: @repzero I converted the image to base64 using an online service, then I put the data in `src` attribute. It worked in browser and apple mail client but not working on Gmail. I find that it is not supported by many email clients including Gmail

Comment: you can upload images on http://imgur.com/upload and then you can use the image src URLs.

Comment: @VipinRaunchhela I have hosted the image in Google Drive, anyway thank you all..

Comment: @vipin hosting on public or free services is not recommended. At times you might end up getting bandwidth exceeded or something similar. Ajay hosting on Google drive will be good, it will be better if it is your company Gmail address (reputation )

Comment: @Syfer Thank you. I am have hosted it on Google Drive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Host the Image publicly in **Google Drive** by sharing the link 'public on the Web' or 'anyone with the link'. Then use this link `http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=FILE_ID` to get direct access to the image. You should replace the `FILE_ID` with actual id from Google Drive link.

Example :

Google Drive Link : `https://drive.google.com/file/d/17iWczcf1T_D4kGRaQYBh6J2XOQI181u6/view?usp=sharing`

Generated Link : `http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=17iWczcf1T_D4kGRaQYBh6J2XOQI181u6`

Now you can use this link in your template.

Comment: Link no more active. 404 error pops up

Comment: @Sujoy Actually you don't have to worry about those exact links you can create your own by following the above-mentioned method. Anyway, I have updated the links. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Base64 has very limited support. Generally speaking it is not advised to use it. You can find information about base64 encoding support in [this tutorial](https://blog.edmdesigner.com/content-images-in-modern-html-emails/#base64encodedimages). It may help to decide if the supported client list is enough or not in your case.

Embedding images in the email is possible by sending them along with the email and reference the sent images with the `img` tag.  A good starter reading for this method is Campaignmonitor’s “[Embedding images revisited](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/how-to/2008/08/embedding-images-revisited/)“ blog post.

The best solution is to host the images with a service provider, which is fast and maintained.
If you use Github, you can also serve images (or any other content) from the GH-Pages branch of a repository.