# Html Email Template - some images are not rendering in Gmail

Tags: html, css, email-templates, xhtml-transitional

I have created a Email template from scratch using `HTML` and inline styles, and added images using http link. The images that have space in the url(in image name) is not rendering in gmail, but it worked in Apple Mail client.

Comment: Check this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437916/html-image-not-showing-in-gmail

Comment: Also, how are you sending the spaces? Can you show an example?

Comment: try adding `%20` in place of space. It should fix things.

Comment: If you're having a similar issue with email templates please checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43248253/5780058)